# React Monorepo using yarn workspaces absolute import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have created the following [monorepo](https://medium.com/frontend-digest/using-create-react-app-in-a-monorepo-a4e6f25be7aa):

```
my-monrepo
|-components
  |-src
     |-folder1
  |-jsconfig.json 
  |-package.json
|-fe1
  |-src 
  |-jsconfig.json 
  |-package.json
|-fe2
  |-src
  |-jsconfig.json
  |-package.json
```

fe1 and fe2 is a react app created with `npx create-react-app`
I used craco, all works well except one thing:

absolute import doesn't work inside components.

I have to say

```
import {test} from './folder'
```

but not

```
import {test} from 'folder'
```

Same thing works on fe1 and fe2.
Why components are different than fe1 and fe2?

The jsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

Comment: `import {test} from 'folder'` here folder means package name, you cant do it like this, you can make an absolute path like `@/components` so webpack can handle both scenario

Comment: Hi, yes I've done that and it works. But I'm going to move a large part of my codebase to from fe1 to components and my aim is to do this without modifying the imports. (that were working fine in fe1) So What I'm after is not possible?

Comment: for a better understanding of code, you must change all imports